# What do these four phrases mean in English?

Tags: translation

I infer from context that the red and beigey-yellow curves are labelled to the effect of "*Confirmed*" and "Suspected*" respectively. Can someone confirm this and also translate the main heading and the tag for blue curves?

[image]

These are from [this web site](https://ncov.dxy.cn/ncovh5/view/pneumonia?scene=2&clicktime=1579582238&enterid=1579582238&from=singlemessage&isappinstalled=0), but will not auto-translate as they are apparently rendered as images instead of text ideograms.

Comment: Try: https://ocr.space/ for ocr-ing.

Comment: @Becky李蓓: Yes, thank you, that answers my question nicely. I have noted the results below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the OCR & translation, with thanks to [user3306356](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/4136/user3306356) for pointing me at the Chinese OCR

[image]

Comment: Must be that yellow fever that's going around, eh?

Comment: @小奥利奥 Uh, yellow fever has totally different connotations...

Comment: @user3306356 woooosh